# Laravel Routing returns page not found

Tags: laravel, routes

I am getting

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found in Laravel

whenever I navigate to `public/index` or `public/home` or `public/post` but when I go to `public/` my view gets delivered and this is the code :

```
*Route::get('\home', function(){
   return view('home');
})->name('home');*
```

Comment: Try changing the slash from "\" to "/" ...Route::get('/home', function(){...}

Comment: Surly the the problem is with the routes.  
Try testing route with Route::get('/home', function(){ echo "Hello";exit; })->name('home');

Comment: I changed it to "/" but still getting the error

Comment: were you able to see the "Hello" word by test route that I mentioned in earlier comment?

Comment: I did not see the hello

Comment: Browser URL : appname/public/home Route : Route::get('home', function(){ echo "Hello";exit; })->name('home'); if it's still not showing Hello then something is wrong

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file elsewhere apart from public folder?

Comment: @Bello, From the issue you have explained it's a .htaccess issue. I have added a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a route for public/ setup in your code, you need something like:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
   return view('home');
})->name('home');
```

Answer (score 1):

you should navigate to `/home` without `public`,

the public folder is the place that your domain points to, and from there your request is processed by your `.htaccess` file so you should not use `public` in your path unless your application logic requires you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is a htaccess issue. You shouldn't be going to link/public/route it should just be link/route

Try changing the root level .htaccess (if you don't have one create one) to:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>
```